# Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at slideshow ERROR

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript and I am trying to create a slideshow inside divs. However when I do it give me the error message

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
>       at slideshow (script.js:14)
>       at script.js:1

This is my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">
                <div id="top">
                    <img class="slide" src="1.png" style="width:100%">
                    <img class="slide" src="2.png" style="width:100%">
                </div>
                <div id="left">
                </div>
                <div id="middle">
                </div>
                <div id="right">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
.slide {
    display:none;
}
```

This is my Javascript code:

```
slideshow();

function slideshow() {
    var index = 0;
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
       slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    index++;
    if (index > slides.length) {
        index = 1;
    }    
    slides[index-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(slideshow, 2000);
}
```

I think the problem is that the javascript cannot access the images when they are in the div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** You are placing the `<script>` file before the slides. So when your script is executed the first time, the markup does not yet exist in `DOM`.
Because your slides do not exist, after the initial `for` (which does nothing), you get to this line

```
slides[index-1].style.display = "block";
```

But `slides[0]` does not exist, so it doesn't have a `.style` property.

**2.** You are reassigning the value of `0` to `index` each time you re-run the function, so it will always show the same slide: the first.

**(3.)** You chose `display` as the method to show/hide your slides, which is not *animatable*. Therefore, your slides will change abruptly, there's no possibility of transition.

**(4.)** In addition, just as a matter of personal choice, I prefer `document.querySelectorAll('.slide')` to `document.getElementsByClassName("slide")`. I don't know exactly why. Probably because it's shorter and maybe because it allows a more flexible selector syntax (classes, ids. attributes or any other valid `css` selector).

Comment: Thank you so much. Your first point solved my problem and now i have a working sideshow. I cant believe how simple the solution was. Thanks Again

Comment: You are welcome (to [so]), @Grandmango227. And happy coding! :: }<(((*> ::